# How to display content preview in Typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid

How would one go about displaying the page content as a list of previews pointing to individual content elements, instead of just displaying them all at once? I will be grateful even for just a conceptual answer.

Comment: Define "preview". Header only? Header + the beginning of the text if it's a "Text" element? Is it supposed be inserted automatically or manually in different parts of the page? Be specific and you might get specific answer. :-) Kitze's answer is good - it will give you a list of content headers (can be changed to something else) but you have to manually insert a new content record on the page.

Comment: Yes, I meant a preview with header and text for instance. What do you mean by "you have to manually insert a new content record on the page"?

Comment: I meant that Kitze's answer relies on you inserting a content record to every page that is supposed to have those previews - this content should be of type "Menu" and the menu type shall be set to "Section index".

Comment: The problem with what you want is the variety of content records in TYPO3 and the resulting decision what shall be displayed. What shall be displayed when on of the content is an image? What if it is a text that contains only a table? What if it is a plugin? There is also a possibility that one of the records is of type "Insert records" which means that you have to create preview of the records the content is pointing at. But maybe none of this applies to your case. We don't know. To get more detailed answer you have to write much more than just two sentences you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

For creating a menu of content elements you can use the content type `menu`, set the menu type to `section index` and select a page.

You can of course modify the output by manipulating the TypoScript.

Here an example that adds parts of the bodytext field and an image. The latter is not tested and written in pseudo TypoScript ;-)

```
tmp < tt_content.menu.20.3.renderObj
page.5 < tt_content.menu.20.3
page.5.renderObj >
page.5.renderObj = COA
page.5.renderObj {
  wrap < tmp.wrap
  stdWrap.typolink < tmp.typolink
  10 < tmp
  10.wrap >
  10.typolink >
  20 = TEXT
  20.field = bodytext
  20.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
  20.cropHTML = 100
  30 = IMAGE
  30.file.import.field = image
  30....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As cascaval suggested, I had a vision of a nicer preview with header + part of body text + maybe a picture when available.

Comment: That's possible with my solution. All you have to do is extend the default TypoScript for that element.